# python valuetype error for any or all

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I got the following error:

```
   while (E_old != E_new) and self.num_iter < 42:
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried to use:

```
while (E_old != E_new) and (self.num_iter < 42).all: but it still gave an issue
```

Can someone assist me with it?

Comment: How does `E_old` and `E_new` look like?

Comment: Try replacing `(E_old != E_new)` with `(E_old != E_new).any()`

Comment: E_old = -1 and E_new = 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: Hmm.  What are `type(E_old)` and `type(E_new)`?

Comment: and self.num_iter is an iterator? do you want in the while loop when any num i s< 42 or all of them?

Comment: post more information please about each variable/object/whatever..

Comment: What is `type(self.num_iter)`, then?

Comment: Nope, don't believe it.  :^)  If the line `while (E_old != E_new) and self.num_iter < 42:` is producing that error message, then at least one of `E_old`, `E_new`, and `self.num_iter` is a numpy array when that line is executed.

Comment: Could you show more context?  I'd suggest printing out the types of `E_old` and `E_new` on *every* iteration.  I suspect that the types might be changing somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueError` that you're seeing comes from NumPy:  it occurs whenever you try to evaluate an array in a boolean context (i.e., interpret that array as being true or false).
There are a few somewhat-related previous StackOverflow questions and answers.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063039/270986) answer for example.

In this context, it seems likely that the problem is that either `E_old` or `E_new` (or possibly both) is a NumPy array.  The expression `E_old != E_new` is then an array of booleans, and NumPy refuses to guess how to interpret this in a boolean context.  If you replace `E_old != E_new` in your expression with `(E_old != E_new).any()`, you should see the problem disappear.  The expression `(E_old != E_new).any()` will be true if *any* component of `E_old` differs from the corresponding component of `E_new`.  If `E_old` and `E_new` match exactly, the expression will be false.

Note: you may also want to look at the [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) method.

Comment: yes, I tried this and got the following error:
    while (E_old != E_new).any() and self.num_iter < 42:
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: Okay.  From your question, I'm guessing there's some sort of iteration and convergence test going on.  Is it possible that `E_old` and `E_new` start out as regular scalars but become arrays at some later iteration?

Comment: So if both of `E_old` and `E_new` are scalars, your original code should be fine.  If either is an array, you'll need the `.all()`.  If they're changing types, then you probably want to think about reworking the code if possible; if not possible, the condition is going to need to be more complicated to accommodate both the scalar and the array cases.